# Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe-animate

i tried making a button that makes it go to the next frame but when i tried it there was an output that said "TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties." i tried to find any script errors but cant find any, heres the script

```
stop();
this.nextbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click);

function click(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    nextFrame();
}
```

this was my first time trying to do actionscript3

Comment: The script has no problems, but it seems that **nextbutton** does not exist at the moment the script executes. Either you put the button instance to another frame, or maybe **nextbutton** is not its instance name, or something else like that.

Comment: thanks! i have been trying to find why it was not working

Comment: The buttons you refer in the script **must** exist on the **same** timeline at the moment of the script execution and must have instance name "nextbutton" (instance name is not a Library symbol name and not a class name either, when you select the object on the stage, there's an Instance Name blank on the Properties panel). Also, Publish Settings > ActionScript3 Settings must have an option "Auto-declare stage instances" on, it is on by default, but still.